# Can I generate a base of eigenvectors of a proper subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I was studying linear algebra and I wondered if given a linear operator $T:V\to V$ defined in some space $V$, under which conditions one can build a base of eigenvectors for a given subspace of $V$.

More specifically, considering for example the case where $\dim V = 3$, I formulated a conjecture:

If $T$ is diagonalizable and $E$ is a subspace of dimension $2$, such that $T (E) = E$, then there is a base of $E$ made up of eigenvectors of $T$

Under these assumptions, there are two possible cases:

$i) \ T (V) = E$

$ii) \ T (V) = V$

Well, I thought it would work out to develop each case, but it didn't work out. Can anybody help me ?

PS: At first, I had not put the hypothesis of $T$ being diagonalizable, but then I thought that if there were no such hypothesis, the statement would be false

Comment: Do you know the key theorem about diagonalisability? - $T:V\to V$ is diagonalisable if and only if $m_T(X)$ (its minimal polynomial) is a product of distinct linear factors? You could then use $m_{T|E}(X)|m_T(X)$ to see that $T$ is diagonalisable on $E$.

Comment: I know it is an expected result, but what guarantees this divisibility of the polynomials?

Comment: $m_T(T|E)=0$ and so $m_{T|E}|m_T$. (The minimal polynomial of $T|E$ generates the ideal of polynomials that kill $T|E$).